# Android Notification widget not showing specified image in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-service

I am not talking about the white icon shown which is the common problem asked in the case of Lollipop.

I am getting no small icon itself when my service is running and in the widget it is not showing my image instead it is showing the ic_launcher image of the andorid.

I have created a music service so I have Play, Pause and Next action which is also not shown in my notification widget. Although it is showing `setContentTitle` and `setContextText` correctly.

My code :

1. Notification part :

   ```
   Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.notification_image);
   Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setContentTitle("Music Player")
           .setTicker("Playing Music")
           .setContentText("My Song")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_image)
           .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon,128,128,false))
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setOngoing(true)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,"Previous",ppreviousIntent)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play,"Play",pplayIntent)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next,"Next",pnextIntent)
           .build();

   startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);
   ```

I have created a list of action constants in my `Constants` class that is being referred to here.

2. Full Function :

   ```
   private void showNotification(){
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
   notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0); //Allow the action to happen as though the main user (MainActivity) is calling.

   Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this,PlayerService.class);
   previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
   PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,previousIntent,0);

   Intent playIntent = new Intent(this,PlayerService.class);
   playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
   PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,playIntent,0);

   Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this,PlayerService.class);
   nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
   PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,nextIntent,0);

   Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.notification_image);
   Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           .setContentTitle("Music Player")
           .setTicker("Playing Music")
           .setContentText("My Song")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_image)
           .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon,128,128,false))
           .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
           .setOngoing(true)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,"Previous",ppreviousIntent)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play,"Play",pplayIntent)
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next,"Next",pnextIntent)
           .build();
   startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);
   }
   ```

I need this : [image]

But I am just getting the Title and ContextText and in the image I am getting the launcher icon and no Play, Previous, Next Button

Edit : I tested the same code in Nexus 5X API 19 and it worked properly. My phone is Lollipop 5.1.1 it is not working.
Also whatever I set as my app launcher icon that is what is shown as the notification icon. And the Action buttons area completely invisible in the notification widget.

The full code here : https://github.com/torrtuga/Music-App

Comment: I did the same for to display player widget in notification.Where you want to show the image ?

Comment: @Debugger The normal widget that is shown in the drop down menu. Like in most Media Players that only. In my case it is showing th launcher icon.

Comment: are you sure 'notification_image' is not default ic_launcher image ?

Comment: @Debugger ic_launcher is in my `mipmap` folder. And `notification_image` I have added in the `drawable` folder.

Comment: Please try the answer i commented below

Comment: Please clean the project and uninstall the app then install

Comment: @Debugger Done. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this @Hack

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable. notification_image))
```

Comment: Nope. The same result. Also see that I am not getting the `small icon` that I am supposed to get, the small white icon at top. It is also not present . And the actions of Pause, Play and Next in the widget are also not there.

Comment: I tested on Nexus 5X API 19 and it worked there. Any idea why this problem is happening in Lollipop?